# Gitlab not sending email when accessed by https

Tags: git, email, https, configuration, gitlab

A couple of months ago I set up GitLab Community Edition in a Debian 8, and our team is successfully using since then. Currently we are using version 9.3.0.

This week our manager said that he wanted to switch the GitLab access to **HTTPS**, so I I created a self-signed certificate and made the following changes to **gitlab.rb**:

```
external_url 'https://srv-git-dev'
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/srv-git-dev.crt"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/srv-git-dev.key"
```

Everything looked it was ok, until someone said that they weren't receiving email notifications. I checked if this was happening for only certain people but realized it wasn't. The entire team had stopped receiving notification mails when I changed the GitLab access to HTTPS...

To confirm this theory, and to check that I hadn't changed any other configuration value by mistake, I commented the above changes and the notifications started to work again...

This is the SMTP configuration (***that I didn't change at any time during this period***):

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "Exchange_Server_Address"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "My_Domain"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
```

This is the analysis I've made so far to try and identify the problem:

**Sidekiq logs**
[image: Sidekiq logs]

---

**> gitlab-rake gitlab:check**

No errors

---

**> gitlab-rails console production**

**ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings**

=> {:address=>"Exchange_Server_Address", :port=>25, :domain=>"My_Domain", :enable_starttls_auto=>false, :tls=>false, :openssl_verify_mode=>"none", :ca_file=>"/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs/cacert.pem"}

---

**> gitlab-rails console production**

**Notify.test_email('my_email_address', 'Hello World', 'This is a test message').deliver_now**

I received the email

---

What am I doing wrong here?

What else can I test?

Because I can't find the relation between configuring GitLab to be only accessible trough HTTPS, and it screwing up the notification system.

Comment: Is `external_url` and `Exchange_Server_Address` a FQDN?

Comment: in [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html), i saw many settings set `openssl_verify_mode ` as `peer`

Comment: @secustor yes, they are both FQDN

Comment: @chenrui tried it and still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't related with the configuration, but to a bug present in the GitLab 9.3 version. I updated to on 9.3.5 and everything is working just fine now.